# Random File Size In CopyTo - C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am sending file data in chunks as per following function. but it behaves randomly.

I am trying to append chunks to same file. But every time file is generated of random size.

If I create files separately per chunk and make total of it (using same below function). It equals. But appending is not working as expected. Do I need to change anything in following function to create big files from chunk?

```
private void AppendToFile(string fullPath, IFormFile content)
{
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));

      using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
      {
           content.CopyTo(stream);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using the FileShare parameter because previously ran into an issue regarding multiple access, which makes me think you are uploading multiple chunks simultaneously. When you open a FileStream with FileMode.Append, it seeks to where it thinks the end of the file is.

So, if you create the file and start writing in thread A, and then another chunk comes in on thread B, thread B will open the file to wherever thread A has already written to, let's say byte 100. If thread A still needs to write more data from its chunk, it will keep writing at byte 101. Thread B will begin writing its chunk at byte 101 as well, and therefore begin overwriting whatever data thread A has written at 101.

You can try to make these operations serial, but because you are receiving them as uploads, I'm guessing that you don't want to do that. In that case, I would suggest writing each chunk to its own separate "partial" file, and then when the last chunk has been received and written, combine the "partial" files into one large file.